# Class referencing itself as a generic?

Tags: java, class, generics, java-8, java-stream

While browsing java 8's stream implementation on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/stream/ReduceOps.java#ReduceOps.ReduceTask), I came upon the following declaration in `java.util.stream.ReduceOps.java` on line 772:

```
 private static final class ReduceTask<P_IN, P_OUT, R,
                                    S extends AccumulatingSink<P_OUT, R, S>>
      extends AbstractTask<P_IN, P_OUT, S, ReduceTask<P_IN, P_OUT, R, S>> {
```

It seems as if the class `ReduceTask` is extending, or better, referencing itself.  Is that really possible?

Comment: There's basically no point to this question and its answer other than to rant about Java's generics. I'm voting to close an unreproducible.

Comment: There really is nothing here that is of value to future browsers: you just misread and didn't notice it was part of a nested type parameter.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My sincerest apologies.  I thought there was no such thing as a [stupid question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18198/there-are-no-stupid-questions-or-are-there). I legitimately spend 5 to 10 minutes writing the question and wondering what the code meant.  I felt that although the solution was rather simple, the time spent writing the question should not be wasted. I am sorry for wasting any of your time.

Comment: I really think this is an interesting question, because at least one principle of OOP. Is there a good reason for doing this?

Comment: @LordT: Yes!  It is certainly an advanced use of generics, but it lets you create base classes that can effectively refer to the self-type of their subclasses.

Comment: One of the oldest advanced Generics examples: `class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`, thus every `enum` is implicitly inheriting `Enum<SelfType>`. This pattern exists since Java 5 and you should have seen (and understood) it before asking questions about other advanced Generics constructs…

Comment: @Holger: Nobody has ever given a satisfactory explanation for that by demonstrating a code example where `class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` works and `class Enum<E>` doesn't.

Comment: @newacct: Since the compiler does it right for `enum` declarations and forbids manual subclassing of `Enum`, it might be impossible to create such a counter-example with a conforming compiler. Still, `Enum<E>` would be wrong, see `Comparable<T>` which allows creating a `class Foo implements Comparable<String>` which makes no sense…

Comment: @Holger: But it is not possible to forbid `class Foo implements Comparable<String>` no matter what you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going on here is that the fourth type parameter (K) to `AbstractTask` is essentially a *self-type*.  The declaration for `AbstractTask` looks like:

```
abstract class AbstractTask<P_IN, P_OUT, R,
                            K extends AbstractTask<P_IN, P_OUT, R, K>>
```

and the Javadoc for K says:

```
* @param <K> Type of parent, child and sibling tasks
```

It has abstract methods like:

```
protected abstract K makeChild(Spliterator<P_IN> spliterator);
```

This pattern actually shows up with some frequency, often in builders, where you've got functionality in a base class (like `AbstractTask`) that wants to reference the type of the concrete subclass, in a type-safe way.  It looks weirdly self-referential, but it is not.

Consider a Builder for a type `Foo`:

```
public interface FooBuilder {
    FooBuilder a(String s);
    FooBuilder b(String s);
    Foo build();
}
```

and `BarBuilder` for a type `Bar`, which extends `Foo`:

```
public interface BarBuilder extends FooBuilder {
    BarBuilder c(String s);
    Bar build();
}
```

Now you want to create a Bar:

```
Bar b = makeBarBuilder()
            .a("a")
            .c("c")       // ERROR
            .build();
```

You have an error at the call to `c()` because the inherited method `a()` returns a `FooBuilder`, which has no `c()` method.  Oops.  You can work around this by using casts to `BarBuilder` but that's ugly too, because you haven't told the type system everything you could have about the relationship between FooBuilder and BarBuilder.

The cure here is to use this tricky self-type pattern:

```
interface FooBuilder<T, B extends FooBuilder<T, B>> { 
    B a(String s);
    B b(String s);
    T build();
}

interface BarBuilder<T, B extends BarBuilder<T, B>> 
        extends FooBuilder<Bar, BarBuilder> {
    B c(String s);
    T build();
}
```

Now you can create a BarBuilder whose inherited Foo methods still return Bar/BarBuilder.  Its tricky to read when you first see it, but pretty powerful.

Comment: "that wants to reference the type of the concrete subclass" But it's not guaranteed to be the type of the concrete subclass

Comment: An interface cannot extend a class, and your non-abstract methods in the class are missing implementations.

Answer (score 0):

`ReduceTask` chooses to extend `AbstractTask` in such a way that it chooses the last type argument in `AbstractTask` to be itself. That's its choice. This is similar to how `String` chooses to implement `Comparable<String>`, i.e. it chooses the type argument of `Comparable` to be itself.

It's also possible to write `ReduceTask` to choose to extend `AbstractTask` with the last type argument being something else, if the author wanted to:

```
class ReduceTask<P_IN, P_OUT, R, S extends AccumulatingSink<P_OUT, R, S>>
      extends AbstractTask<P_IN, P_OUT, S, SomeOtherTask<P_IN, P_OUT, R, S>>
```

(assuming that `SomeOtherTask` satisfies the given bound for that type parameter in `AbstractTask`.)

There's no way in Java for `AbstractTask` to guarantee that a subclass extends it to have the last type argument be exactly the same as the class.